# How to add json dictionaries to a list of lists

Tags: python

I have created some code to merge json documents (aka dictionaries) that I need to merge by looping through them and then adding them to a list of 'merged' json documents (myList).

So myList is a list of lists containing jsons!

Here is a snapshot of the code that is adding the 2 jsons. It took me a while to figure out a solution and only after I added the first line (it appears I have to initiate a new list), it worked. Otherwise I would get an 'out of index-range' error.

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

```
for ....
    myList.append([])
    myList[cnt].append(dict1)
    myList[cnt].append(dict2)
    cnt += 1
```

Comment: Get rid of [cnt] and just use myList.append(dict)

Comment: He is using list of lists of dicts, not list of dicts.

Comment: Not enough info - you need to post, how do you make decision, to which list of lists you append given dictionary.

Comment: What about `myList.append([ dict1, dict2 ])` ?

Comment: As for Radoslaw's comment: The snippet is the part that creates an entire new list and then adding the 2 documents.  I could have put the cnt at the beginning but since the index starts at 0, I decided to increase cnt afterwards.  Adding to an existing list works fine just by finding the relevante index and add via myList[foundIndex].append(dict1).   Btw. I am using this to merge addresses using fuzzywuzzy for matching.

Comment: And Mezba is right: That creates the same result.  Quite a brain twist I must have had.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mer mezba's comment. A much simpler way of doing this is

```
for ....
     myList.append([ dict1, dict2 ])
     cnt += 1
```

This will create a new list within mylist and add both json docs (as dictionaries). Adding to an existing list can still be done using e.g.

```
     myList[someExistingIndex].append(dict1)
```